# Write a function that implements the bridge detection algorithm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, networkx

Algorithm: Bridge Detection Algorithm

Require: connected graph G(V,E)

1. return Bridge Edges
2. bridgeSet={}

3.for e(u,v) ε E do

4. G'= Remove e from G
5. Disconnected = False;
6. if BFS in G' starting at u does not visit v then
7. Disconnected = True;
8. end if
9. if Disconnected then
10. bridgeSet= bridgeSet U {e}
11. end if
12. end for
13. Return bridgeSet

---

1. Imports all relevant modules / packages (like NetworkX, etc.);
2. Uses the functionnetworkx.read_gmlto load the co-appearance network of characters of the novel“Les Misérable”. The data are available from the homepage of Prof. Mark Newman, which is onlineat www-personal.umich.edu/ mejn/netdata/;
3. Calls the implemented bridge detection function on theLes Misérablenetwork, and prints all de-tected bridge edges, one edge per line.

I used networkx. 
Then read:

G=nx.read_gml('lesmis.gml')
print (nx.info(G))

I have the idea but don't know how to implement it on jupyter: copy then remove from the copy so we don't have to do any tricks in implementation. I truly need help and I am stuck...

---

so far this is my output:
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 77
Number of edges: 254
Average degree:   6.5974
False

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX already has an algorithm for bridges searching: [`networkx.algorithms.bridges.bridges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bridges.bridges.html#networkx.algorithms.bridges.bridges):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(30, 0.08, directed=False, seed=1)
list(nx.bridges(G))
```

> `[(0, 2), (10, 12), (12, 28), (13, 24), (15, 28), (23, 24)]`

If you need the source code, you can find it [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/bridges.html#bridges) and [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/chains.html#chain_decomposition):

```
@not_implemented_for('multigraph')
@not_implemented_for('directed')
def bridges(G, root=None):
    chains = nx.chain_decomposition(G, root=root)
    chain_edges = set(chain.from_iterable(chains))
    for u, v in G.edges():
        if (u, v) not in chain_edges and (v, u) not in chain_edges:
            yield u, v
```

Comment: I did use the built in function list(nx.bridges(G)), but we are supposed to not do that. I need to remove an edge from G in a bfs, and i am not sure how to do so.